# What does 'the forward theorem' refer to?

Tags: geometry, terminology, circles

I have seen the following in a *circle geometry* proof in a Cambridge textbook:

> We have proven that angles at the circumference standing **on the same arc** of a circle are equal. The converse of this is:
>
> If two points lie on the same side of an interval, and the angles subtended at these points by the interval are equal, then the two points and the endpoints of the interval are concyclic.
>
> **The most satisfactory proof makes use of the forward theorem.**
>
> Let P and Q be points on the same side of an interval AB such that ∠APB = ∠AQB = α.
>
> Aim: To prove that the points A, B, P, and Q are concyclic.
>
> Construction: Construct the circle through A, B and P, and let the circle meet AQ (produced if necessary) at X. Join XB.
>
> Proof: **Using the forward theorem**,
> ∠AXB = ∠AQB = α (angles **on the same arc** AB).
> Hence ∠AXB = ∠AQB,
> so QB ∥ XB (corresponding angles are equal)
> But QB and XB intersect at B, and are therefore the same line.
> Hence Q and X coincide, and so Q lies on the circle.

What is meant by 'the forward theorem'? Is it just referring to the *original* theorem of which this theorem is the converse (the 'converse of the converse')?

Or is there a theorem known as 'the forward theorem'?

Comment: @WillHunting I have updated the question with more from the textbook.

Comment: If it appears that what's being used is the original theorem, then surely that's what's meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess. I think forward here means the *forward* implication (versus the backwards implication which you are currently proving).  So they're just using the original theorem.